# Designing a proxy with non-blocking pipe forwarding to another server

Tags: c, pipe, ipc, iperf

I have written a proxy which also duplicates traffic. I am trying to duplicate network traffic to a replica server which should receive all the inputs and also process all the requests. However only the responses on the main server are visible to the client. The high level workflow is as follows

```
Thread 1. Take input from client forward it to a pipe in non-blocking way, and to the server
Thread 2. Read from server and send to client
Thread 3. Read from pipe and forward to replica server
Thread 4. Read from replica server and drop
```

The code is available in this gist: https://gist.github.com/nipunarora/679d49e81086b5a75195ec35ced646de

The test seems to work for smaller data and transactions, but I seem to be getting the following error when working with iperf and larger data sets:

```
Buffer overflow? : Resource temporarily unavailable
```

The specific part in the code where the problem is stemming from:

```
void forward_data_asynch(int source_sock, int destination_sock) {
  char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
  int n;

  //put in error condition for -1, currently the socket is shutdown
  while ((n = recv(source_sock, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0)) > 0)// read data from input socket 
    { 
      send(destination_sock, buffer, n, 0); // send data to output socket
      if( write(pfds[1],buffer,n) < 0 )//send data to pipe
        {
          //fprintf(stats_file,"buffer_overflow \n");
          //printf("format string" ,a0,a1);
          //int_timeofday();
          perror("Buffer overflow? ");
        }
      //DEBUG_PRINT("Data sent to pipe %s \n", buffer);
    }

  shutdown(destination_sock, SHUT_RDWR); // stop other processes from using socket
  close(destination_sock);

  shutdown(source_sock, SHUT_RDWR); // stop other processes from using socket
  close(source_sock);
}
```

The reading process is as follows:

```
void forward_data_pipe(int destination_sock) {

  char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
  int n;
  sleep(10);
  //put in error condition for -1, currently the socket is shutdown
  while ((n = read(pfds[0], buffer, BUF_SIZE)) > 0)// read data from pipe socket 
    { 
      //sleep(1);
      //DEBUG_PRINT("Data received in pipe %s \n", buffer);
      send(destination_sock, buffer, n, 0); // send data to output socket
    }

  shutdown(destination_sock, SHUT_RDWR); // stop other processes from using socket
  close(destination_sock);
}
```

Please note, the pipe has been defined as follows:

```
/**   Make file descriptor non blocking */
int setNonblocking(int fd)
{
  int flags;

  /* If they have O_NONBLOCK, use the Posix way to do it */
#if defined(O_NONBLOCK)
  /* Fixme: O_NONBLOCK is defined but broken on SunOS 4.1.x and AIX 3.2.5. */
  if (-1 == (flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0)))
    flags = 0;
  return fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
#else
  /* Otherwise, use the old way of doing it */
  flags = 1;
  return ioctl(fd, FIOBIO, &flags);
#endif
}
```

Could anyone help in fixing what could be the reason of the error?

Comment: Too many unclear questions, no [mcve]. Read [ask].

Comment: @Olaf - Thanks for pointing out. I have added details and highlighted the error

Comment: `write` returns -1 on error. Most probably, when the pipe is closed by the reading process. Note that `write` does not necessarily write the whole buffer, so your program is wrong and may skip part of messages. If the reading process expects messages in some format, maybe, it issued an error and closed the pipe.

Comment: @Marian - please have a look, it does not take any particular format. I also check that read process does not die. I have copied the function which does the reading.

Comment: @Marian - Also the whole code is in gist link provided

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case is that data is sent too fast to the socket that has been set to non-blocking mode. You have several options:

1. Accept the fact that data may be lost. If you do not want to delay the processing on the main server, this is your only option.
2. Don't set the socket to non-blocking mode. The default mode, blocking, seems like a better fit for your application if you don't want data to be lost. However, this will also mean that the system may be slowed down.
3. Use poll(), select(), kqueue(), epoll(), /dev/poll or similar to wait until the socket has enough buffer space available. However, when using this, you should consider why you set the socket to non-blocking mode in the first place if you nevertheless want to block on it. This also leads to slowdown of the system.

Comment: as you mention, I do not want to delay processing on the main server. Which is why this has been set as non-blocking. How do I differentiate between overflow and other errors for a pipe?